# QT ui not showing up when MainWindow initated from another class (not in the main function)

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

Is it possible to initiate the object of MainWindow in QT and call the show method from another class, for example inside a thread class constructor, and then create the thread object in the main function and start the thread? It does not work for me (the ui flashes and disappears immediately). Is there any way to fix it? If not, how can I control buttons and other stuff from the thread. How can I communicate between them (the thread and ui class) by exchanging data?

My program looks like this. Thread constructor:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

void thread::thread(){
    MainWindow m;
    m.show();
}
```

and the main function:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    thread t;
    t.start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Try changing `MainWindow m;
    m.show();` to  `MainWindow *m = new MainWindow;
    m->show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but before that you have to connect your MainWindow to the thread object. You should never call from another thread than the GUI-thread functions that modify the GUI.

The solution would be to use slots/signals. All the communication from threads to the UI is always done with slots and signals.

Below an example:

Create a signal in your Thread class called `mySignal();`

```
class Thread {

...

signals:
  void mySignal();

... 
}
```

and create a slot in your MainWindow

```
class MainWindow {

...

public slots:
 void ShowWindow();

..

}
```

Create a function in your MainWindow class called showWindow()

```
void MainWindow::ShowWindow() {

this->show();

}
```

Connect your thread to the MainWindow

```
connect(threadObject, &Thread::mySignal, this, &MainWindow::ShowWindow);
```

Call the slot from your thread with `emit mySignal();`

**PS: Your application should be a widget application not console.**

Comment: `connect(threadObject, &Thread::mySignal, this, &MainWindow::ShowWindow());` or `connect(threadObject, &Thread::mySignal, this, &MainWindow::ShowWindow);`, is typo?

Comment: @ eyllanesc you are right, it should be `&MainWindow::ShowWindow`. I have corrected it.

Comment: I think that the error is caused because an object that is created in a function only exists in that function, and in the end it is eliminated. Have you tested your solution?

Comment: Your code: `void MainWindow::ShowWindow() { MainWindow m; m.show(); }`, it seems unnecessary, `void MainWindow::ShowWindow() { show(); }`

Comment: @ eyllanesc When I wrote the answer I knew his object were going out of scope. I didn't even mention it, because it's wrong to allocate the mainwindow on heap from your thread. The correct approach is to use a widget application and use signals and slots from your thread to the gui thread.

Comment: I do not dispute that and I agree, and even then your answer has other errors.

Comment: If you create a widget in a ShowWindow () method, it will only exist in that method, so in the end it will be eliminated (that happens in a few milliseconds) and you will never see the widget.

Comment: @ eyllanesc In my approach I just wanted to demonstrate the use of the signal/slots technique. It should be enough to use `this->show()` and `this->hide()` within the MainWindow class. I just updated the answer. PS: MainWindow is allocated on the stack in a widget application too.

Comment: a good quality answer must address and solve all the problem, besides it is not necessary to create a slot, you can use show directly: `connect(threadObject, &Thread::mySignal, this, &MainWindow::show, Qt::QueuedConnection);` :P

Comment: @ eyllanesc My answer is correct and addresses his problem, I will not delete it. you can call it in a slot, lamba or directly. That's up to you. Also your comment is wrong that you recommend him to allocate on the heap. :-(

Comment: Who told you to eliminate it? I just give you my observations to improve your response. Relax, whenever a question is deleted, I will tell you directly

Comment: @ eyllanesc that's fine :) Have a happy new year.

Comment: I do not know where you call that method, if you call it in the QThread constructor it's fine, if you do it in run() it will show you errors, the question is not good because it is unclear, so I have not proposed any answer, I I wait for an answer and cross-question the author to have a correct idea of what he wants.

Comment: Remember that QThread is not a thread, it is just a thread handler. :P

Comment: what I am trying to do is controlling 100s of buttons in the MainWindow class from a thread doing the logic so what should I do, you said I can not access directly the UI elements from the thread, so how can I do this? or Do I have to create 100s of signals and 100s of slots to connect the two?

Comment: @ser rea yes, you cannot access the UI from your thread. Even if you manage to do so, it can result into unexpected application crashes. You have to do some kind of logic and connect all these buttons with signals and slots. You can use loops and have multiple connections to one button. it's not exactly clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I have solved the problem.